Understanding Halmos "Finite Vector Spaces" theorem §12: a subspace has lower dimension than dimension of space it lives in.
In Halmos (Finite Vector Spaces book), Paul Halmos provides a proof of the fact that any subspace $M$ of a space $E$ of dimension $n$ has a dimension less or equal than $ n$. He starts with:

"It is possible to give a deceptively short proof of this theorem that runs as follows. Every set of $n+1$ vectors in $E$ is linearly dependent, hence the same is true of $M$; hence, in particular, the number of elements in each basis of $M$ is $\leq n$."

He then proceeds with a second part of the proof:

"The trouble with this argument is that we defined dimension $n$ by requiring in the first place that there exist a finite basis, and then demanding that this basis contain exactly $n$ elements. The proof above shows only that no basis can contain more than $n$ elements; it does not show that any basis exists."

What exactly is he talking about in his second part?
From my understanding he takes a basis of the subspace $M$ and then notice it is linearly independent in $E$ as well. So he concludes that the cardinal of this basis is $\leq n$. This, I have understand.
Then, my further understanding (of the second part) is that, while we know the existence of a basis for $E$, we are not ensured that $M$ has a basis.
Am I getting this right?
Thanks in advance.
PS: I've found this duplicate, that proves the same theorem but uses concepts I am not familiar with (chain of irreducible closed subsets) and that are not alluded to in Halmos' book.

Your understanding of both parts is correct.

@AnneBauval I would argue that Halmos is not "tak[ing] a basis of $M$" in the first part. He is only arguing that any set with more than $n$ elements is dependent, and therefore that any linearly independent subset has at most $n$ elements. This implies that if there is a basis then it has at most $n$ elements, but he never considers a basis for $M$.

@ArturoMagidin I disagree, he writes "the number of elements in each basis of $M$ is $\le n$". He doesn't consider a basis of $M$ but he considers "each" of them (although perfectly knowing he didn't yet prove there exists any, which he will do in the second part).

My point is that what the OP describes as "his understanding" is not the argument Halmos is presenting, but rather a consequence thereof.

So, your point is that the OP's quote (recalled above) is not faithful? I didn't check.

My quote is not unfaithful. I just didn't provide the "third part" of the proof, where (I think, if I understood well) Halmos proves $M$ is finite dimensional.

No, I'm saying that Halmos's argument isn't "Let $B$ be a basis for $M$. Then $B$ has at most $\dim(V)$ elements". The argument is "A set with more than $\dim(V)$ elements is linearly dependent. So any basis for $B$ would necessarily have at most $\dim(V)$ elements."

@ArturoMagidin I agree Halmos did not write that. But in a proof of the statement "The number of elements in each basis of $M$ is $\le n$", it would be acceptable to start it "Let $B$ be a basis for $M$..." and then reason about the number of elements in $B$. "Taking" a basis in this sense is not asserting the existence of a basis.

(Page references are to the UTM printing)
Halmos defines finite-dimensional vector space (p. 10) and the dimension of a vector space (p. 14) as follows

Definition. A vector space $V$ is finite-dimensional if it has a finite basis.


Definition. The dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is the number of elements in a basis of $V$.

So, say $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and $W$ is a subspace. In order to prove that the dimension of $M$ is less than or equal to the dimension of $V$, we need to prove two things:

That $M$ is finite-dimensional (otherwise, we can't even talk about it having a dimension at all!)
That any finite basis of $M$ has at most as many elements as the dimension of $V$.

What Halmos is getting at is the following: you can certainly show that $M$ cannot contain a linearly independent set with more than $\dim(V)$ elements. So if it were to have a basis, this basis would necessarily have at most $\dim(V)$ elements. However, this does not prove that $M$ is finite-dimensional: it only proves that $M$ cannot contain a set with more than $\dim(V)$ elements that is linearly independent. As a consequence, if $M$ has a basis, then that basis cannot have more elements than $\dim(V)$. Note that he is not assuming that $M$ has a basis, he does not take a basis. Instead, he is arguing by contrapositive:

If $S\subseteq M$ has more than $\dim(V)$ elements, then $S$ is linearly dependent.

This is equivalent to saying "If $S\subseteq M$ is linearly independent, then $S$ has at most $\dim(V)$ elements."
But this only implies 2. He never actually takes a basis. And it does not establish 1, which one still needs to prove to complete the argument.
